# Habilitar el compartir con FileProvider en Android

Tags: android

tengo el siguiente codigo que permite visualizar una imagen QR creada previamente(Uso FileProvider),pero cuando la imagen se muestra la opcion compartir esta deshabilitada, como puedo solucionarlo?

```
    Uri uri;
    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, my_imagen);
    Intent intento = new Intent();
    intento.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intento.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intento.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intento);
```

Comment: ¿Tienes los permisos para usar FileProvider?

Comment: si claro, el problema solo se me presenta en dispositivos huawei

Comment: Puede que esto te ayude [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41309223/11063757), tiene un problema similar con los huawei